# How can I write a function to find the Percentiles in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a lesson at w3school, it's talking about Machine Learning. There's one unit about Percentiles, it talks about how to use NumPy to find Percentiles. But I don't want to use NumPy's function, I want to write one myself, but I was bugged in the middle, could anyone tell me how to write it? Thank you.

I can't find the way to calculate it even in a mathematic way, help!

Comment: There is even a wikipedia article on it...

Comment: Hmmm.....................

Comment: what are those? I don't understand...